# Uncaught TypeError: this.reset is not a function - error empting input after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, reset

Problem trying to clear input after AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "river_flow.php",
  data: 
  {  username: $("#username").val(),
     idv:$("#idv").val(),

     comment: $("#comment").val()},

  cache: false, 
   success: function(data){    $(".read_comment").after(data); this.reset();
     alert('success');
   }})   
 return false;
```

Says:  Uncaught TypeError: this.reset is not a function.
Here is my form:

```
 <div class='post_comment'>
                   <input type="hidden" id="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>" name='username'/>
                   <input type="hidden" id="idv" value="<?php echo $row['idv']; ?>" name='idv'/>
                   <input type='text' class="input_comment comment" value='' placeholder='What do you think?' name='comment' id='comment' />
                   <input type='submit' name='comment_submit' class="comment_submit comm" id='comm'/>        
         </div>
```

I've tried this as well:

```
 $(this).find('.comment').reset();
```

Doesnt work. Cant find out why. I ve set class to comment and called it along with javascript function reset and it says reset is not a function. Same with this.reset. Need help, please.

Comment: `console.log(this);`, what do you see? Because I'm certain it's not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

following to clear comment from textbox:

```
$("#comment").val('');
```